# Thin or thick REST-client?

Tags: rest, web-applications

We have mobile application which takes data from server (REST API)

There are two methods:

- /v1/movies (returns movies: id, title, image_url ...)
- /v1/likes (returns movies id that user likes)

Mobile application has a view "My likes" which contains movies that user likes, and this view must also contain necessary metadata (id, title, image_url ...)

I see a few solutions:

1. Return more info about movies in the "/likes/" method
2. Create new method "/movies/likes/"
3. Mobile app should make 2 requests.

I know, this is choice between flexibility and speed.
Where is the border when application becomes thin client instead of thick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the best approach for a scalable application is to make as few HTTP requests as possible. To do this, you should include information about other resources in the data sent back for the initial resource request. **The key** is to mark the other data as being a different URI, which your client can then cache under a different URI.

[Take a look at HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html). HAL provides a *representation* of the requested resource, as well as some metadata, which include the URIs of other resources it is linked to (`_links`) and allows full copies of those other resources to be in-lined with the response (`_embedded`).

This give you the maximum bang per request, until we get HTTP/2.0 which will allow multiple request inlining.

I don't use the terms "thin" and "thick" client. Every line of code makes it slightly thicker, and there is not a boundary delineating the two.